# Existing 20amp tandem breaker with 14/2 wires for basement light

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, code-compliance, recessed-lighting

We purchased this house in Marlboro, NJ in 2019. It had finished basement with permit. Basement has drop ceiling and 2x2 fluorescent light containing U-shaped lights. I noticed that basement has a 20amp breaker but these lights were wired with 14/2 wires. ([image: See attached image of the breaker panel][image]).

[image: Solar Disconnect Outside]

I am planning to remove those 2x2 lights and use the 14/2 cable that was feeding power to them in a junction box and take out 2 'branches' from that junction box to install wafer recessed lights.

Overall amperage will be lower than what the light fixtures were using.

My question was if I can use 14/2 for the new wiring coming out of the junction box or should I use 12/2.

Answer (score 6):

### Breaker is the wrong size

The core problem is #14 wire on 20A breakers - you have to address that!

Extending the circuit with #12 does not fix the problem!  You must deal with the #14/20A problem.

The only feasible answer is to replace the relevant 20A breaker(s) with 15A breaker(s).  And this opens up another can of worms:

### All the breakers need to be replaced *anyway*.

The "Challenger" breakers are known fire-starters and must be eliminated with the ferocity one would use on an FPE panel. The good news is, with Challenger, there's nothing wrong with the basic bones of the panel, so you only need to change the breakers.

And in even better news, the proper breaker is super easy to come by, since all BRyant/Eaton "BR" breakers *are also Type C*, the correct type for your panel. This is approved by UL, and fully documented.

Better news still, Eaton BR breakers are cheap - $5 a trip typically.

So you're talking under $100 to replace all the faulty breakers with the correct BR duplex breakers, either 15/15, 15/20 or 20/20 as the wires require.  And you'll be able to take care of all the overbreakering wire problems at the same time.

You also need to replace the Siemens/Murray MHT breaker in lower left - that was never legal or safe in this panel. Someone went "Challenger is obsolete, I'll just use *whatever*" because they didn't know the above.

---

The main breaker is also of the Challenger type deemed a firestarter. Swapping that is more complicated. The power company will have to turn off power at the meter.  Consult with the local Eaton dealer for the correct breaker for this; note the bolt-down feature which is required.  I would expect a BR2100, and $40ish.

Comment: Thank you.. Siemens/Murray MHT breaker - I assume you meant in the lower right, 20/20 one. And that's the one that's 20 amp with 14/2 wire I'm talking about. I wonder how did it approve inspection and permit. Also, to replace those brakers, turning off the main on the upper right,  100/100 one,  should be enough,  iis that right?  FYI - We have solar panels installed. Do I need to ahut that off also from outside?

Comment: @blackroses -- shutting off the main will cause the inverters to kill the solar (anti-backfeed protection)

Comment: @blackroses *eyeroll* yeah, that's typical of contractors like solar, hot tub etc.  They don't want to carry 6 kinds of breaker on the truck, so they pick one 1" breaker type and pretend it's compatible with all 1" lines.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Sorry, if it came out like that but didn't mean to nitpick about the location. Just wanted to be sure. I am a newbie. I can change receptacles, some wiring for a new receptacle, remove can light and install wafer recessed, GFCI and like.
If you could please, I am still not crystal clear on what should I shutoff to safely change breaker. Should I disconnect Solar AC disconnect outside home (see image above) only or PV disconnect along with the main breaker (100/100) in the upper left corner?

Comment: @blackroses I think he was _eyerolling_ at the people who installed the solar using the wrong breakers because it's easier for them to stock one type. I don't think it was aimed at you (though I could be wrong...)

Comment: @blackroses yes, Freeman has it correct, I was eyerolling the *sadly typical* behavior of installers who are not licensed electricians, and refuse to bring in a licensed electrician for that work as the law requires, and who leave messes other people must resolve.  *What YOU said was fine*.

Comment: Why must the power be off at the meter to change the main breaker? Does this apply to the main breaker in any panel? Does it apply to the upper section breakers in a split bus panel? Wouldn't it be OK to change these breakers with the panel powered if the breaker is switched off and not wired when it is pulled out or snapped it?

Comment: @JimStewart Because changing a main breaker *with the power on* is sheer idiocy.   That's the whole point of a main breaker, it is the first switch past the meter.  It cannot be de-energized except by the power company pulling meter or service drop.   **There is no breaker between the main breaker and the transformer.  As much as 10KA or even 25KA can flow**.  Even when a switch is off, one side of it is hot.  Go get a voltage tester and check some of  your light switches. Same deal.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Still have some doubts...Please let me know which option to go with to safely replace this MHT breaker in the lower-right. 

I will switch off individual breaker BEFORE switching off main breaker anyway.

A) Switch off PV Disconnect for Solar panels outside the house followed by switching the main breaker in the panel.

B) Switch off only main breaker in the panel (not sure what anti-backfeed is. Re: @ThreePhaseEel comment above).

C) Switch off only Solar disconnect - I highly doubt this is even an option but putting it here anyway.

Comment: @blackroses pretty easy.  A) switch off everything in this panel. B) Pop off the deadfront.  C) switch off this breaker *extra hard* and it will actually rock out. Remove it altogether with the wires still attached to it.  **At this point, the breaker is stone dead** and you can remove the wires and move them to the new breaker.  Reverse to reinstall.  *The breaker doesn't need to be installed in the panel to attach the wires*.

Comment: Good to know Solar disconnect switch doesn't need to be turned off. Thank you again.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-BR-2-20-Amp-Single-Pole-Tandem-Non-CTL-Circuit-Breaker-BR2020/100153768 is this correct breaker/type to use to replace 20/20 siemens tandem in the lower right corner of the panel?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the 20 A breaker with 15 A. If part of the branch circuit is 14 AWG, then it's good practice to use 14 AWG for the new part as well. That reduces the risk that someone will think it's all 12 AWG and upgrade the breaker to 20 A again.